# Are there any source that I can download ACPI table 2.0+ for QEMU?

Tags: qemu, acpi

After using SeaBIOS for a while, I realized that it's too old. I want to use ACPI 2.0+ for finding and using HPET instead of PIT and APIC timer. I have searched on Google and I know that I can add additional ACPI table to QEMU, but the problem here is I can't find any source for downloading ACPI. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: There is no source, if you are talking about non-existing platform (and it's your case, because SeaBIOS provides an abstact platform). You may create entire table set from scratch using ACPI specifications. That said, it maybe not so easy task, but feasible with patching SeaBIOS code and writing missing pieces yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`qemu-system-x86_64 -M hpet=on` should do the trick.

HPET emulation is off by default because of the virtualization overhead.  qemu generates acpi tables matching the emulated hardware, so when the HPET is enabled it will also show up in the ACPI tables.

Comment: Okay, After I tried, it said: "Property .hpet not found". What should I do?

Comment: Same error with qemu-4.2, but no such error when passing `-M hpet=on` to qemu-6.2. But it still reports ACPI version 1.